# Looking for the correct way to use "DoubleValueRange" in OptaPlanner

Tags: java, linear-programming, optaplanner

I am learning about how to use OptaPlanner via solving linear programming. I know there are quite a lot of LP solvers, but I think it's a good start point for me to understand the modeling.

But When I started to work on it, I run into a problem that it looks like the entity planning variable can only be countable.

The exception is like below:

```
The selector is not countable, check the ValueRanges involved.
Verify that a ValueRangeProvider does not return ValueRange when it can return CountableValueRange or Collection.
```

Can I know:

1. What's the "legitimate" way to use the "DoubleValueRange"?
2. Is there a "best practise" for LP in OptaPlanner?

Thank you.

My solution:

```
@PlanningSolution
public class Solution {
    @PlanningEntityProperty
    private Entity entity;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score = HardSoftScore.ZERO;

    public Solution(Entity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "x_1")
    public ValueRange<Double> getX1Range() {
        return ValueRangeFactory.createDoubleValueRange(0.0, 100.0);
    }

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "x_2")
    public ValueRange<Double> getX2Range() {
        return ValueRangeFactory.createDoubleValueRange(0.0, 100.0);
    }
...<getters setters>...
```

My Entity:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Entity {
    private long id;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "x_1")
    private Double x1;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "x_2")
    private Double x2;
...<getters setters>...
```

My constraints:

```
...
    private Constraint c1(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(Entity.class)
                .filter(e -> !(3.0 * e.getX1() + 5.0 * e.getX2() < 5.0 ))
                .penalize("C1", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }

    private Constraint c2(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(Entity.class)
                .filter(e -> !(2.0 * e.getX1() - 6.0 * e.getX2() > 0.0 ))
                .penalize("C2", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }

    private Constraint min(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.from(Entity.class)
                .penalize("MIN", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, e -> (int)(-e.getX1() + 6.0 * e.getX2()));
    }
...
```

Comment: LP solvers are way better in solving LPs than OptaPlanner which is really a glorified heuristic (this is not bad: these algor ithms are excellent for problems where exact methods run out of steam). Good LP solvers can handle (sparse) problems with tens of millions of variables and constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the return types from the ValueRangeFactory's createXXXValueRange() method set, I notice that all, apart from one, are returning a *Countable*ValueRange. The one exception to that rule is createDoubleValueRange(), which is returning a "mere" ValueRange (ValueRange).

You error points in the same direction : the ValueRange isn't considered being a valid *countable* ValueRange. It makes sense to me : OptaPlanner wants to select from a set of *discrete* values to do its moves. So I don't think there's any "legitimate" way to use it for OptaPlanner's solver Move's.

For a reason I can't identify, I myself wouldn't take OptaPlanner as my first choice to solve LP problems, as the set of feasible solutions can be calculated. But using OptaPlanner anyhow (like in your case), I would then work with multiples (of 10, 100, 1000, ...) of *discrete* values (in the result calculation dividing them by 10, 100, 1000, ...). AND/BUT at the same time, I would be extremely cautious to avoid score corruption, the danger of which would never be very far away.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, OptaPlanner currently (8.3 or lower) doesn't have any move selectors to deal with `DoubleValueRange`s. See the Investment Portfolio example on how to plug in your own to deal with bounds based value ranges such as DoubleValueRanges.

That being said. If your value ranges are truly continuous (so not discrete), you're indeed probably better off with an LP instead. Note that in most planning problems, value ranges are discreet because you can't send 0.75 of a vehicle/person to location A and the other 0.25 of it/him/her to location B.

See also sudo's fine answer.